# How can I apply a user-defined row function onto all rows of a loaded in array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have written a user defined function that loops through a row of values in order to give the number of zeros between values (distance between values). Those distances are appended into a list and then averaged for a final value of average distance between values. The function works great when I load in a CSV file with just one row of values. However, I would like to be able to apply the function to a file with multiple rows, and then report the output of each row into a dataframe.

This is all being run with python 3.7. I attempted to create a nested loop in order apply the function manually. I have tried the numpy.apply_along_axis function. I have also tried reading the file in as a pandas dataframe, and then using the .apply() function. However, I am a bit unfamiliar with pandas, and when I replaced the numpy indexing in the function with pandas indexing, I began to generate multiple errors.

When I load in a larger CSV file and try to apply it to file[0] for example, the function does not work. It seems to work only when I load in a file with one row of values.

```
def avg_dist():
     import statistics as st


    dist = []
    ctr=0

#distances between events

    for i in range(len(n)):
        if n[i] > 0 and i < (len(n)-1):
            if n[i+1]==0:
                i+=1
                while n[i]==0 and i < (len(n)-1):
                    ctr+=1
                    i+=1
                dist.append(ctr)
                ctr=0
            else:
                i+=1
        else:
            i+=1


#Average distance between events
    aved = st.mean(dist)
    return(aved)
```

Comment: Could you provide a working example? Just from your problem description, you might want to take a look at the map function: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest response is at the end of the answer.  There have been several edits.

The very end (4th edit) of the answer has a completely new approach.

I'm not certain what you're trying to do but hopefully this can help.

```
import numpy as np

# Generate some events
events = np.random.rand(3,12)*10.
events *= np.random.randint(5, size=(3,12))<1
events
Out[36]:
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  5.35598205,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  6.65094145,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  6.04581361],
       [ 6.88119682,  4.31178109,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  1.16999289,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ]])

# generate a boolean array of events.  (as int for a compact print.)
an_event = (events != 0).astype(np.int)
n_event

Out[37]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

def event_range(arr):
    from_start = arr.cumsum(axis=1)
    from_end = np.flip(arr, axis=1).cumsum(axis=1)
    from_end = np.flip(from_end, axis=1)
    return np.logical_and(from_start, from_end).astype(np.int)
```

event_range function step by step.
from_start is the cumsum of an_event.  zero before any event, >0 after that.

```
from_start = an_event.cumsum(axis=1) # cumsum the event count.  zeros before the first event.
from_start
Out[40]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # zeroes before the first event.
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

from_end is the cumsum of an_event but from max to min. Therefore zero after the last event.

```
from_end = np.flip(an_event, axis=1).cumsum(axis=1) # cumsum of reversed arrays
from_end = np.flip(from_end, axis=1) # reverse the result.
from_end
Out[41]:
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], # zero after the last event.
       [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

logically anding these together to get, zeroes before the first event, ones after that and zeroes after the last event.

```
ev_range = np.logical_and(from_start, from_end).astype(np.int)
ev_range
Out[42]:
# zero before first and after last event, one between the events.
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],  
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

n_range = ev_range.sum(axis=1)
n_range
Out[43]: array([ 1, 11,  8])

n_events = an_event.sum(axis=1)
n_events
Out[44]: array([1, 2, 3])

avg = n_range / n_events
avg
Out[45]: array([ 1.        ,  5.5       ,  2.66666667])
```

Should avg be n_range/ (n_events-1)? i.e. count the gaps, not the events.

What would you expect for only one event in a row?  What for zero events in a row?

**Edit following comments**

To count gaps longer than zero gets a bit involved.  The easiest is probably to take the differences for consecutive columns.  Where these are -1 there is a 1 followed by a zero.  You need to add a final zero column to your data in case the last column has an event in it.

```
np.random.seed(10)

test = 1*(np.random.randint(4, size=(4,12))<1)

test
Out[24]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

temp = np.diff(test, axis=-1)

temp
Out[26]: 
array([[ 0,  1, -1,  1, -1,  0,  1, -1,  0,  1, -1],
       [ 0,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0, -1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1, -1,  0]])

np.where(temp<0, 1,0)
Out[28]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

In [29]: np.where(temp<0, 1,0).sum(axis=-1)-1
Out[29]: array([3, 3, 1, 0]) # should be [3, 4, 1, 0]
```

Add a column of zeros to test.

```
test = np.hstack((test, np.zeros((4,1), dtype = np.int)))
test 
Out[31]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

temp=np.diff(test, axis=-1)

temp
Out[35]: 
array([[ 0,  1, -1,  1, -1,  0,  1, -1,  0,  1, -1,  0],
       [ 0,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1,  0, -1], # An extra -1 here.
       [ 0,  0,  1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0, -1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1, -1,  0,  0]])

np.where(temp<0, 1,0).sum(axis=-1)-1
Out[36]: array([3, 4, 1, 0])
```

As I said, a bit involved.  It may be easier to loop through but this should be faster if more difficult to understand.

**2nd Edit following another idea.**

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)
test = 1*(np.random.randint(4, size=(4,12))<1)
test

Out[2]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

temp = np.diff(test, axis=-1)

np.where(temp<0, 1, 0).sum(axis=-1)+test[:,-1]-1
# +test[:,-1] adds the last column to include any 1's from there.
Out[4]: array([3, 4, 1, 0])
```

**3rd Edit**

Thinking this through I created 2 functions, I also show a do_divide which copes with divide by zero.

```
import numpy as np

def zero_after_last_event(arr):
    """
    Returns an array set to zero in all cells after the last event
    """
    from_end = np.flip(arr, axis=-1).cumsum(axis=-1) # cumsum of reversed arrays
    from_end = np.flip(from_end, axis=-1) # reverse the result.
    from_end[from_end>0] = 1  # gt zero set to 1
    return from_end

def event_range(arr):
    """ event_range is zero before the first event, 
        zero after the last event and 1 elsewhere. """
    return np.logical_and(arr.cumsum(axis=-1), zero_after_last_event(arr)).astype(np.int)

def do_divide(a, b):
    """ Does a protected divide.  Returns zero for divide by zero """
    with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'): # Catch divide by zero
        result = a / b
        result[~np.isfinite(result)] = 0.
    return result
```

Set up a test array

```
np.random.seed(10)
events = 1*(np.random.randint(4, size=(4,12))<1)
events
Out[15]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

With the functions and data above above this follows.

```
# Count gap lengths  
gaps = 1 - events # invert the values in events (1->0, 0->1) 
gaps = np.logical_and(gaps, event_range(events)).astype(np.int)
gaps
Out[19]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

sumgaps = gaps.sum(axis = -1)
sumgaps
Out[22]: array([5, 4, 4, 0])

# Count how many gaps
temp = np.diff(events, axis=-1) # temp is -1 when an event isn't immediately followed by another event.
n_gaps = np.where(temp<0, 1, 0).sum(axis=-1)+events[:,-1]-1
# +test[:,-1] adds the last column to include any 1's from there.
n_gaps
Out[23]: array([3, 4, 1, 0])

do_divide(sum_gaps, n_gaps)
Out[21]: array([1.66666667, 1.        , 4.        , 0.        ])
```

**4th Edit - using np.bincount**

```
import numpy as np

def do_divide(a, b):
""" Does a protected divide.  Returns zero for divide by zero """
    with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'): # Catch divide by zero
        result = a / b
        result[~np.isfinite(result)] = 0.
        return result

np.random.seed(10)
events = 1*(np.random.randint(4, size=(4,12))<1)

cumulative = events.cumsum(axis=1)
cumulative
Out[2]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])

bin_count_len = 1+cumulative.max()  # Biggest bins length required.

result = np.zeros((cumulative.shape[0], bin_count_len), dtype=np.int)
for ix, row in enumerate(cumulative):
    result[ix] = np.bincount( row, minlength = bin_count_len )

result
Out[4]: 
array([[2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
       [3, 5, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [9, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Lose column 0.  Its before any events. Lose the last column, always after the last event. The gaps include the opening event, -1 removes it from the gap size.

```
temp = result[:, 1:-1]-1   # 
temp
Out[6]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  2,  1, -1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 4,  0,  2, -1, -1],
       [ 2, -1, -1, -1, -1]])
```

Set any cell temp[r, n] = 0 if temp[r, n+1]==0

```
temp_lag = (result[:, 2:]>0)*1
temp_lag
Out[8]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

temp *= temp_lag
temp
Out[10]: 
array([[1, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

tot_gaps = temp.sum(axis=1)
n_gaps = np.count_nonzero(temp, axis=1)

tot_gaps, n_gaps
Out[13]: (array([5, 4, 4, 0]), array([3, 4, 1, 0]))

do_divide(tot_gaps, n_gaps)
Out[14]: array([1.66666667, 1.        , 4.        , 0.        ])
```

HTH

Comment: 2 values next to each other would be a distance of 0. One event in a row would also be a 0. And no events in a row would be a 0 as well

Comment: thank you for your response. Your approach almost exactly addresses what I am trying to achieve, I think what I am trying to accomplish would make more sense if I provide an example. Using the events array you provided initially, here's what the expected output would be. The first row would just be 0. The second row would have one distance at a value of 9.  The third row would have one distance at a value of 5.

Comment: And yes, the avg would be over the number of gaps rather than events

Comment: Do you want the average over all gaps, or just over gaps longer than zero?

Comment: Yes, the average would be over gaps longer than zero

Comment: I've edited the answer to show a way to count gaps gt zero.  HTH

Comment: An alternative poach (probably faster) is to add the final column to the sum.  I've edited the answer again.

Comment: I am wanting to get a sum of zeros between values in a row (only count zeros that are between values, anything else gets counted as a 0), and then divide that by the number of gaps longer than 0 (in that row) and return that average. Rather than returning the number of gaps in the row

Comment: I missed the original question, too focused on how to count gaps. 3rd edit in the answer.

Comment: Would there be  a way to view the distance values for each row that contribute to the sum? Essentially a matrix in which each row would have the distance values that correspond to that row in the array

Comment: I've only got my phone with me until next week.  It should be possible to do something using np.bincount with arr.cumsum. This can count how many times each cumsum occurs on each row. Try it and see.

Comment: np.bincount(arr.cumsum(axis=1))

ValueError: object too deep for desired array                                                                         I keep receiving this error whenever I try to use that

Comment: [link Documentation] (numpy.bincount.html?highlight=bincount) . It takes a 1d array as the parameter. I think it needs a for loop through the rows of the array. It may be useful to use the min length parameter to get every row to return the same size array.